# Windows Schdule tasks through c# and asp net given access denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, scheduling

I created a schdule through C# and asp.net. It's working in the development serverment, but live server it has given the below issue

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

public Task CreateTask(string name) 
{
    Task tester = OpenTask(name);
    if (tester != null) {
    tester.Close();
    throw new ArgumentException("The task \"" + name + "\" already exists.");
    }
    try {
        object o;
            //Error Occrured at this below line of Code
        its.NewWorkItem(name, ref CTaskGuid, ref ITaskGuid, out o); 
        ITask iTask = (ITask)o;
        return new Task(iTask, name);
        }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {                       
       throw objException;          
    }   
}
```

Comment: Does the server allow the application to schedule tasks? Usually web application run with restricted priviledges on behalf of special IIS account, and permissions for manipulating/interacting with OS components must be specifically set. You should provide more details on your configuration and even some more code.

Comment: This is the only code we are using to create task. I agree with you it required special permissions to create tasks. so that I've customized account mapped with IIS directory secuirty

Comment: Please let me know what else you required ?